# nested WinJS.UI.Listviews in html (metro application)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Here are the html :

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h4 class="title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
    <div class="list" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none' }"></div>
</div>


<div class="groupeditemslist" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none' }"></div>
```

How Could I add `data-win-options` in full html (no javascript templateSelector like "[Metro: Dynamically Switching Templates with a WinJS ListView](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/05/23/metro-dynamically-switching-templates-with-a-winjs-listview.aspx)" of the nested `WinJS.UI.ListView` to bind data?

For each item in the main data, I add a `WinJS.Binding.List`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are in format:

```
var firstLevelDataSource = new WinJS.Binding.List(
    [{title: "t1", secondLevelBinding: new WinJS.Binding.List([1])},
     {title: "t2", secondLevelBinding: new WinJS.Binding.List([2])}]);

// then you expose firstLevelDataSource as Data.firstLevelDataSource
```

Then, wouldn't this work?

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h4 class="title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
    <div class="list" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none', itemDataSource: secondLevelBinding.dataSource }"></div>
</div>

<div class="groupeditemslist" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none', itemDataSource: Data.firstLevelDataSource.dataSource }"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not... I get a `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'dataSource' of undefined or null reference`. It was, of course, my first idea ;)

Comment: @enguerran Good to know that it didn't work. Though, I don't really understand why it didn't. I did similar stuff with a ListView within FlipView, but I used the dynamic template. :(

Comment: when you say "dynamic template", you tell us that you add a new ListView with javascript on currentItem with the template selector method? I think I will go back to this solution (I implemented before but find nicer to have the code in html)

Comment: @enguerran I completely agree. I think all of my `ListView` or `FlipView` started with HTML code, but ended up with Javascript template due to all kinds of limitations.